# for each row, i want to add addtional rows for each value in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to take a row of data and create new rows for each value in specific columns.

So I want to take col3, col4, and col5 and create new rows for each of the column values

```
    table 1 
     col1     col2     col3     col4     col5
     01      John      123      345      123
     02      Bob       111      222      NULL
```

I want the output to be

```
 table output
  col1    col2    [new]
   01     John     123
   01     John     345
   01     John     123
   02     Bob      111
   02     Bob      222
```

I am unsure what approach to take with this. I looked into transposing the columns using pivot but, I can't seem to make it work out without using some aggregate function.

Comment: What db do you use?

Comment: i'm using microsoft sql server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the [`unpivot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) operator in sql server.

```
select a.col1
, a.col2
, a.new
from table1 as t
unpivot ([new] for col_nm in ([col3], [col4], [col5])) as a
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to unpivot the data.  I think the best method is via a lateral join using the `apply` keyword:

```
select v.*
from table1 t1 cross apply
     (values (t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3),
             (t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col4),
             (t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col5)
     ) v(col1, col2, [new])
where [new] is not null;
```

This is better than a method using `union all`, because the original table is scanned only once.

Comment: There was no platform given when I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use cross join to get more rows:

```
Select
 t.col1
,t.col2
,case 
 when dat.row_type = 1 then t.col3
 when dat.row_type = 2 then t.col4
 else t.col5
end as new_col
From table t
Cross join (
 Select 1 as row_type
 Union all select 2
 Union all select 3
) dat
Where (dat.row_type = 1 and t.col1 is not null)
Or (dat.row_type = 2 and t.col2 is not null)
Or (dat.row_type = 3 and t.col3 is not null)
```

Comment: This does not work as described since it includes rows with NULL in them.

Comment: I have edited my answer, now my code excludes null rows

Answer (score 0):

The best way is with union all.

Like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM table1
WHERE col3 is not null

UNION ALL

SELECT col1, col2, col4
FROM table1
WHERE col4 is not null

UNION ALL

SELECT col1, col2, col5
FROM table1
WHERE col5 is not null
```